# $_FILES empty whith videos at the server (works great in local)

Tags: php

In php, `$_FILES[]` is not set (!isset) when the file size is more than 1mb.  When is smaller works fine.  When i work in localhost works fine too, but in the server not.

I configure the php.ini

- max_execution_time = 3000
- max_input_time = 3000
- memory_limit = 512M
- upload_max_filesize = 70M
- post_max_size = 70M

In the server i have IIS

Comment: After you changed the settings in the php.ini, did you restart apache2?

Comment: `phpinfo()` check the values are actually used, and that you edited the right php.ini

Comment: I'm not using apache, i using IIS. The changes are edited fine, i used the php info to see them

Comment: I think it may be because IIS configuration have a limit with POST, can be that?